# how to access other textbox on same line On asp:gridview using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to get value for txtQuantity on javascript :

```
 <asp:gridview ID="gvPOAdd" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDeleting="gvPOAdd_RowDeleting">
        <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">
            <ItemTemplate>

                <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Quantity") %>' CausesValidation="false" Enabled='<%# ((Session["isNewPurchaseOrder"] != null) && ((bool)Session["isNewPurchaseOrder"] == true )) ? false : true %>'></asp:TextBox>
                <br />

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Unit Cost">
            <ItemTemplate>

                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtUnitCost" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" onkeyup="calculateTotalCharge(this,'<%= txtQuantity.clientid %>');" ></asp:TextBox>


            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Cost">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div style="text-align:right;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTotalCost" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
```

PS : 
    onkeyup="calculateTotalCharge(this,'<%= txtQuantity.clientid %>');

and I am using the following script :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function calculateTotalCharge(unitcost,quantity) {               
            alert(unitcost.value);           
            alert(quantity.value);
        }
```

// But I get an error quantity is null ?!

how to access other textbox on same line On asp:gridview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are comfortable with Jquery then Change `onkeyup` to this `onkeyup="calculateTotalCharge(this);"`

```
function calculateTotalCharge(obj)
{
    var vUnitCost = $(obj).val();
    var vQuantity = $(obj).parent().prev().find('input[type=text]').val();
    //alert('UnitCost: '+ vUnitCost + 'Quantity: ' + vQuantity);
}
```

> Description:

1. `$(obj).parent()` will return you parent object basically a `<tr>`
2. Then `.prev()` will return you previous `<tr>` object.
3. Inside that you can find and get the text box value `.find('input[type=text]').val()` within same row.

Comment: not working with me ..error : TypeError: unitcost.parent is not a function

Comment: Please see my update code. There was a minor issue, it has been fixed now :)

Comment: this is work thanks  .could you please tell me how to set  next label value on same lint (next to unitcost ... is there opposite of prev() lilke next () ?!!       var totalcost = $(unitcost).parent().next().find('Label').val();

Comment: Yeah there's a property named `next()` you can apply same.

Comment: what i should use instead of[ input[type=text]] because it is label ?!

Comment: Surprabhat Biswal   var vTotal = $(unitcost).parent().next().find('labe]').val(); give me undefind

Comment: Label when render as HTML it becomes span so you need `$(obj).parent().prev().find('span').html();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97869/discussion-between-mohamad-mahmoud-and-suprabhat-biswal).

Comment: iam trying to edit a value of a TD like this: $(obj).parent().next().next().innerHTML = "sample_text"; but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

I would use Rahul's way but just an alternative is below:

Use `RowDataBound` event of gridview as below.

```
 <asp:gridview ID="gvPOAdd" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDeleting="gvPOAdd_RowDeleting" OnRowDataBound="gvPOAdd_RowDataBound">
```

C#

```
    void gvPOAdd_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if(e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
            {
                TextBox txtQuantity= e.Row.FindControl("txtQuantity") as TextBox;
                TextBox txtUnitCost= e.Row.FindControl("txtUnitCost") as TextBox;

                txtUnitCost.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "calculateTotalCharge(this,'" + txtQuantity.Text+ "');");
            }
        }
    }
```